# rosbag meta data

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to extend the bag file format with a description field that explains how the data was achieved/recorded. Or at least a link to a document that gives this details.
I was thinking of something like:

```
rosbag record /tf -m "this was recorded for IROS paper 2011 with <settings> active and female test person, more info in bag_specs.txt"
```

Or even a:

```
--detail-file="_bag_specs.txt"
```

Perhaps there is such a functionality that I'm not aware of? (and no I don't want to be putting this into a topic which is also recorded)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9382/rosbag-meta-data/) by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I go further in implementing such functionality? Is there interest from WG to give support? Do I file a ticket?

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tim Field](https://answers.ros.org/users/297/tim-field/) on 2011-03-25**:
Please open a ticket and we can discuss the feature there.  Thanks.

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-16**:
This would indeed be my next question, how should we implement this?

**Comment by [Tim Field](https://answers.ros.org/users/297/tim-field/) on 2011-03-16**:
A ticket would be good; a patch better.  We've held off on implementing this as there's room for abusing the feature, but it's been demanded enough and is useful in enough circumstances that I think we should pull the trigger.  I like your -m option.